# How to dump list of file's from subfolders with its full path in Linux

Tags: linux, command

I am not able to get the command (or group of commands)to do the following operation in Linux:

I am having a main `project_folder` with some 10 `sub_folder` containing all different extensions of files (for example **`*.cpp /*.txt/*.y / *.py`** etc ). But I want to just make a list of all `REQUIRE_*.txt` files from all SUB-FOLDERS with its complete path and dump into the text file .

For example :

`result_dump.txt` should include :

```
user/project_folder/sub_folder0/a0.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder0/a6.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder0/a11.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder0/a12.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder1/a1.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder1/a13.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder2/a14.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder2/a15.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder2/a2.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder3/a3.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder4/a4.txt
user/project_folder/sub_folder5/a5.txt
--
--
--
```

If I use below command ,then I am getting all files information which is not my intention:

```
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\.*' | sort
```

**Note:** Please let me know how I can dump that result in text file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below command from the user's home directory

```
find project_folder/ -maxdepth 3 -type f -name REQUIRE_*.txt
```

**Edit**

You can then redirect the o/p using to a file adding `> result_dump.txt` after the command

Comment: I want to just find REQUIRE_*.txt file's list only in my dump.txt file .How I can modify your mention command in this

Comment: My sub_folders has different names of text file .But I am interested in  REQUIRE_*.txt files only

Comment: @jailaxmik The expected result doesn't show any file starting with **REQUIRE_**. I have updated my answer. Adjust the max depth as per your requirement.